# Не загружает данные, при втором нажатии

Tags: ajax

1. При следующем нажатии на кнопку не подгружает следующие сообщения. Загружает по нажатию только 1 раз.
2. Как заставить его автообновляться, так как он срабатывает на нажатие по кнопке.

Код элемента:

```
function updateLoader(){
    function loader(){

        $("#load div").click(function(){
            $("#imgLoad").show();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/app/ajax/loader.php",
                data: { id: <?php echo $dg['id'] ?>, coll: num },
                complete: function(data){
                    if(data == 0){
                        $("#imgLoad").hide();
                        $("#load div").hide();
                    } else {
                        $(messageListLoad.html(data.responseText)).append(data);
                        num = num + 5;
                        $("#imgLoad").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
    setInterval(loader, 3000);
}
```

Comment: @rnddev, во-первых, выполнять какие-то действия с ответом сервера, лучше не в complete, а **success**. Во-вторых, зачем вам вложенная функция? В-третьих, если запускать в цикле следующий запрос, то нужно хотя бы убедиться, что предыдущий прошёл нормально (опять же **success**). В-четвертых, для таких целей, я бы использовал setTimeout, а не setInterval. И в-пятых, вы вызвали функцию "loader". А в ней что? Опять ждём клик по кнопке, но никак не автоообновление.

Comment: @rnddev, А может не работает потому, что возникает ошибка? Над этим не задумывались? Ведь на то он и **success**, что выполняется в случае успешного завершения запроса, а **complete** выполнится в любом случае, даже если ошибка и была. 

Не ставил за цель полностью исправить ваш код. а просто показать примерную схему. [Смотрим тут][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/667jkp58/

Comment: @rnddev, консоль у вас открыта? Есть какие-то ошибки? Вы наблюдаете, как уходят ajax-запросы, как возвращается ответ? Что в этом ответе?

Comment: @rnddev, вы чем пользуетесь? Инструментами Chrome, Firebug или еще что-то? Если в Chrome, то перейдите в закладку "Network".

Comment: @Deonis loader ничего не возвращает, такое ощущение, что он в бесконечном цикле, оно не так работает как нужно. он постоянно обновляется, а нужно только при добавлении сообщения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Комментарии закончились...*

[[@rnddev](/users/19883/rnddev)](/users/19883/rnddev), можно до бесконечности гадать, что у вас там происходит. Наверно, когда-нибудь и угадаем, но это не дело. Делайте поэтапно: для начала, добейтесь, чтоб запросы нормально отправлялись и вы видели, что ответ возвращается. Для этого, на сервере пока ничего не мудрите, а отправляйте один подготовленный ответ.

```
if(isset( $_POST['id'], $_POST['coll'] )){
    exit('Ок');
}
```

Всё! Когда будете видеть, что ajax отрабатывает нормально, тогда уже переходите к серверной части.

Comment: Мне всё ясно, complete вместо success было потому что с success данные дублировались, вместо того чтобы обновляться.